# How to dynamicaly create a variable in a for?

Tags: python, variables, twitter

I have a simple for :

```
for tweet in tweets.xpath("/tweets/tweet/content"):
        count = count+1
        print("Tweet n°%s" % count)
        print("=> " + tweet.text)
        print("===================================")
```

And I wanna know how can I do to create automatically a variable to get every tweets here in a different variable, if there are 30 tweets so 30 differents variables are automatically create.. I don't know if I'm clear but thanks for any help !

Comment: Why you are not using an array?

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: What do you want to use the variables for later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use an array:

```
from lxml import etree
xmldoc = etree.parse("tweets.xml")

tweets = xmldoc.xpath("/tweets/tweet/content/text()")
```

To access any of the tweet texts, access them by an index:

```
print "first one", tweets[0]
print "last one", tweets[-1]
print "number of tweets", len(tweets)
```

I know, you asked for dynamically creating new variable names for the values,
but you would have to provide information about those dynamically created
variables to later processing.

On the other hand, if you consider `tweets[1]` a "variable name", you have the
solution you asked for.

**EDIT:** Code modified not to reuse variable `tweets` for multiple purposes.

Comment: I used this code (here is the code: http://pastebin.com/Ja0MG8me) but i got this error:  `===================================
 Getting tweets from tweets.xml... 
===================================
Tweet n°1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 34, in <module>
    tweets[count].sort()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: @CorentinBarreau There is no need for `for` loop as `xmldoc.xpath(...)` returns all the text values you need. I have modified my answer not to reuse variable `tweets` which was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can do:

```
for count, tweet in enumerate(tweets.xpath("/tweets/tweet/content")):
    print("Tweet n°%s" % count)
    print("=> " + tweet.text)
    print("===================================")
```

If you want to store the result, you can do:

```
tweets = dict()
for count, tweet in enumerate(tweets.xpath("/tweets/tweet/content")):
    tweets[count] = tweet.text
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how it's creating a different variable for each tweet.. :/

Comment: @CorentinBarreau I edited the example using a dict, creating a variable for each tweet would be a *bad practice*.

Comment: Thanks dude, that's exactly what i needed, nice job !

Comment: I just tried your code, I have : `for count, tweet in enumerate(tweets.xpath("/tweets/tweet/content")):
        tweets[count] = tweet.text
        print("Tweet n°%s" % count)
        print("=> " + tweets[count])
        print("===================================")` and i got this error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 30, in <module>
    tweets[count] = tweet.text
TypeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object does not support item assignment
`